# The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Iam getting this error 'The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"' while trying to Generate a scaffold to test database connectivity.How can i rectify this error in ruby on rails in windows platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit application, or vice-versa.  The application architecture must match that of the DSN.

If you are using a 64-bit version of windows, then the default is for it to use the 64-bit version of the ODBC administrator.  To access the 32-bit version use:

```
c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

And set up your DSN here.

Comment: how it is possible..will you explain it briefly.

Comment: how can i set the application architecture match that of DSN

Comment: The DSN architecture relies on that of the underlying driver. Check your driver version. Also, what version of Windows are you using? 32 or 64 bit?